# NSArrayController automatically selects all new items on `add:` action

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an `NSArrayController` which is bound to my `NSTableView`. The table view has the standard `+ / -` buttons.

When I press the `+` button which triggers the `add:` action of the `NSArrayController` the new item in the list will automatically be selected, which prevents the user from editing the text in a `NSTextField` inside of the cell.

In IB the selection property of the table view `multiple` is not checked so multiple-selection shouldn’t even possible and is also not possible “by hand”.

I had to change the `Highlight` to `None` to work around the problem but now I am no longer able to delete individual columns, which is kind of fine in my case, but I am wondering how this could be solved, ideally without implementing a delegate (I prefer to just hook up stuff with the bindings for such a standard case).

[image: highlight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, every time you add an item to the NSArraycontroller, it gets selected in the [NSTableview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Have you selected the [preserveSelection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/preservesSelection) and deselected the [avoidEmptySelection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/avoidsEmptySelection) of the NSArraycontroller? You also have to uncheck "selectInsertedObjects".

[image]